# What is the account code in genesis account?

Tags: frontier, testing

What does `account code` use for? No idea why are **0xff (INVALID)** and **0x00 (STOP)**...

https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/08dfe8986e3f92ce213244c438eb9178653fce59/primitives/evm/src/lib.rs#L87
https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/08dfe8986e3f92ce213244c438eb9178653fce59/frame/evm/src/tests.rs#L45
https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/08dfe8986e3f92ce213244c438eb9178653fce59/frame/evm/src/tests.rs#L56

Comment: Perhaps related to [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/195)

Comment: heyy @forgetso... thanks!! that is!!!